# filter posts based on checkboxes in a form

Tags: php, wordpress, html, forms

I've built a form on a WordPress custom post type archive page that filters said posts using values pulled from a taxonomy and set with select multiple fields. The form submits to the same page. It's probably built "the long way round" but it works.

However, now I'm being asked to change the select multiple fields to Checkboxes and I can't seem to get it right. The checked values aren't being passed when the form submits.

Here's my code with my attempt to turn one of the two selects into a set of checkboxes. This first batch just sets the values to be pulled in:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $topics = get_field('program_topic');
        foreach( $topics as $topic ): ?>
            <?php $program_topic_names[] = $topic->name ; ?>
            <?php $program_topic_links[] = $topic->slug ; ?>
            <?php $topic_name_results = array_unique($program_topic_names) ?>
            <?php $topic_link_results = array_unique($program_topic_links) ?>
        <?php endforeach;
        $types = get_field('program_type');
        foreach( $types as $type ): ?>
            <?php $program_type_names[] = $type->name ; ?>
            <?php $program_type_links[] = $type->slug ; ?>
            <?php $type_name_results = array_unique($program_type_names) ?>
            <?php $type_link_results = array_unique($program_type_links) ?>
        <?php endforeach;
endwhile; 
$final_topic_results = array_combine($topic_name_results, $topic_link_results);
$final_type_results = array_combine($type_name_results, $type_link_results);
endif; 

//print_r($final_topic_results);
//print_r($final_type_results);


wp_reset_postdata();
```

And the Filter Row / Form:

```
<!--    Filter row  -->
    <div class="row filter_row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col span_3_of_12">
            <h2>Find a Program</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_9_of_12">
            <form id='program_filters' class='program-filters multiple' method="post" onsubmit="showHide(); return false">
                <h4 class="span_12_of_12 no_padding" style="font-weight: 700;">Select one or more Topics and/or Types</h4>
                      <div class="styled-select multiple span_7_of_12">
                       <fieldset name="program_topic" id="program_topic">
                        <?php
                            foreach( $final_topic_results as $key => $value ):
                                echo "<input type='checkbox' ".checked( $_GET['program_topic'], $key )." value='$key' name='$key' /> $key <br>";
                            endforeach;
                        ?>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div class="styled-select span_3_of_12">
                        <select multiple name="program_type" id="program_type">
                            <?php
                                foreach( $final_type_results as $key => $value ):
                                echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['program_type'], $key )." value='$value'>$key</option>";
                            endforeach;
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                   <div class="button_col span_2_of_12">
                   <input type='button' id='submitFormData' value='Find' onclick="this.form.submit()";>
                   <input type='button' value='Reset' onclick="window.location.href='/programs/'">
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:left;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--    Filter row  -->
```

And here's the Post type code I didn't include before:

```
<!--    Program row     -->
<div class="container program-list-wrap"><ul>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
$dateformatstring = "l, F d";
$unixtimestamp = strtotime(get_field('program_date'));
$instructor = get_field('program_instructor_name'); 
$instructorInfo = get_field('program_instructor_info');
$program_date = get_field('program_date');
$current = time(); ?>
    <?php if($current < $unixtimestamp || empty($program_date) ) : ?>
    <li><div class="program list">
    <div class="row program-intro">
    <div class="col span_9_of_12">
    <div class="program-vitals">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
    <?php if(get_field('program_date')) : ?><div class="program-date-time"><h4><?php echo date_i18n($dateformatstring, $unixtimestamp); if(get_field('program_time')) : ?> &mdash; <?php the_field('program_time');?><?php endif; ?></h4></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php $types = get_field('program_type');
            if( $types ): ?><div class="types">
                <?php $i = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach( $types as $type ): ?>
                    <strong><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $type ); ?>"><?php echo $type->name; ?></a></strong><?php $rowCount = count( get_field('program_type') ); if($i < $rowCount): echo ', '; endif; $i++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?></div>
        <?php $topics = get_field('program_topic');
            if( $topics ): ?><div class="topics">
                <?php $i = 1; ?>
                <?php foreach( $topics as $topic ): ?>
                    <strong><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $topic ); ?>"><?php echo $topic->name; ?></a></strong><?php $rowCount = count( get_field('program_topic') ); if($i < $rowCount): echo ', '; endif; $i++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($instructor):?><strong>Instructor:</strong> <?php echo $instructor; if($instructorInfo):?>, <?php echo $instructorInfo; endif; endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?></div>
    <?php if(get_field('program_intro')) : ?><div><?php the_field('program_intro'); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_3_of_12">
        <?php $register = get_field('program_registration_url'); $registerAlum = get_field('program_alum_registration_url'); $cost = get_field('program_amount'); $brochure = get_field('program_brochure_url') ?>
            <div class="button_col"><h2><?php echo $cost ?></h2><a href="<?php echo $register ?>" class="action_button sml">Register Here</a><a href="<?php echo $registerAlum ?>" class="action_button sml">UMKC Alumni Registration</a> <?php if( $brochure) :?><a href="<?php echo $brochure ?>" class="action_button sml" target="_blank">Download a brochure</a><?php endif; ?></div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="action_button">Learn More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="program-extras">
            <?php if(get_field('program_includes')) : ?><div><h4><strong><?php the_title() ?> Includes:</strong></h4><?php the_field('program_includes'); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(get_field('program_learn')) : ?><div><h2>What You Will Learn</h2><?php the_field('program_learn'); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(get_field('program_key_topics')) : ?><div><h2>Key Topics</h2><?php the_field('program_key_topics'); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(get_field('program_attendee')) : ?><div><h2>Who Should Attend</h2><?php the_field('program_attendee'); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(get_field('program_instructor')) : ?><div><h2>About the Instructor</h2>
        <?php $image = get_field('program_instructor_photo');
        if( !empty($image) ): ?><div class="program_instructor_photo"><img src="<?php the_field('program_instructor_photo'); ?>);" /></div><?php endif; ?>
        <?php the_field('program_instructor'); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
    </div>

        </div></li>

        <?php endif; ?>
            <div style="clear: left;"></div>    
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
    </ul></div>
<!--    Program row     -->
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where you defined your variables: `$program_topic_names,$program_topic_links,$program_type_names,$program_type_links`?

Comment: move out your lines with `array_unique()` from foreach loops

Comment: Moved those out and the arrays still return exactly as expected, thanks for that. But it didn't help with the Checkbox issue, the real issue. I'm assuming it's because Select fields return strings and checkboxes are true/false/0/1 so I need an extra if then in that fieldset I changed to a checkbox. But I can't figure out how to squeeze that in with automated values.

Comment: how are you trying to get values from post? where is your code?

Comment: That first bit of code gets the Taxonomy fields (program_topic & program_type) used in each custom post type (programs) post,  cleans it up and combines the Names and Slugs into one key/value array for each taxonomy type. The second bit of code assigns the values of those taxonomies to two different Multiple Select fields in a form. Whichever taxonomies are selected by the user get passed via POST method and the page resets loading only the posts containing those taxonomies. I'm sure there's a better way to explain it but I suck at that.

Comment: Sorry, just went in and added the code that inserts and styles the Post type itself on the page, in case that's what you meant.

Comment: all are clear, but how you're processing the POST request? ( after click on the form `                   <input type='button' id='submitFormData' value='Find' onclick="this.form.submit()";>
` button, you should to process values )

Comment: It's just using the built in Wordpress POST handling. It's processed and reloaded on the same page.